# Call DELETE method of wcf restful service from client applicaiton

Tags: wcf, client

Here is how I try to call the DELETE method from my WCF service:

```
string tmpUrl1 = "http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/EndPoint/MyMethod";
WebRequest request1 = WebRequest.Create(tmpUrl1);
request1.Method = "DELETE";
byte[] byteArray1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"idName\":" + newIdName + "}");
request1.ContentType = "application/json";
request1.ContentLength = byteArray1.Length;
Stream dataStream1 = request1.GetRequestStream();
dataStream1.Write(byteArray1, 0, byteArray1.Length);
dataStream1.Close();
WebResponse response1 = request1.GetResponse();
```

But I get error 400.

Here is the method's name in the wcf:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "DELETE",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/MyMethod/{deleteRP}/",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
                )]
    MyClass MyMethod(string deleteRP);
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service and inspect the  trace log for the actual error. Also your url address should have something like

```
"http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/EndPoint/MyMethod/55"
```

rather than

"http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/EndPoint/MyMethod"

UPDATE:

```
private static byte[] ToByteArrayUsingDataContractSer<T>(T requestBody)
        {
            byte[] bytes = null;
            var serializer1 = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
            serializer1.WriteObject(ms1, requestBody);
            ms1.Position = 0;
            var reader = new StreamReader(ms1);
            bytes = ms1.ToArray();
            return bytes;
        }
```

Now replace the following line

```
byte[] byteArray1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"idName\":" + newIdName + "}");
```

with

```
byte[] array = ToByteArrayUsingDataContractSer<string>("{\"idName\":" + newIdName + "}");
```

Comment: Well byteArray1 is giving the '55' part of the link

Comment: I guess there is a problem when its trying to deserialize your bytearray being posted on the server. Please find the code to serialize the request. Hope that would help you out

Comment: I use the same code for calling POST methods (only instead of DELETE I put POST) and everything is ok. So that's not it.

Comment: Can you try to send the string value as part of the url rather than writing it to the stream. I have tried writing to the stream and could not succeed but when i send it as part of the url i get a 200 status code.